# How to connecte to sql sever NET6 visual studio 2022 asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

i try to modify my local db connection (which works fine) in the appsettings.json :

```
 "ApplicationDbContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=CateringMilano;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

with the sql server connection :

```
 "ApplicationDbContextConnection": "Data Source=SQL5101.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=db_9b307b_cateringmilano;User Id=db_9b307b_cateringmilano_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

but when i run the project i got a strange error:

local host does  not exists..

and also

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
```

SqlException: Failed to generate SSPI context.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)

and also i cannot see the sql server db in visual studio sql explorer..

What do i need to connect my website to my sql sever db?  what am i missing to do?

Thanks

Comment: Hello Tamil, did you able to made any progress on it? Let us know how its going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to connect your remote hosting SQL server instance with your application instead of location database instance. If that is the scenario then your database connection string should like below:

***When used in web.config file:***

> `data source=SQL5101.site4now.net;initial catalog=db_9b307b_cateringmilano;User Id=db_9b307b_cateringmilano_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;integrated security=False;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True; />`

***When used in appsettings.json:***

```
"ConnectionStrings": {

    "DefaultConnection": "Server=SQL5101.site4now.net;Database=db_9b307b_cateringmilano;User Id=db_9b307b_cateringmilano_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;integrated security=False;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  }
```

[image]

***When used in Ado.net connection string file:***

```
  using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=SQL5101.site4now.net;Database=db_9b307b_cateringmilano; User Id=db_9b307b_cateringmilano_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;integrated security=False;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"))
            {
             

            }
```

***Tips to check if the connection successful :***

- Go to your `SQL Server Managament Studio` and click on below tab:

[image]

- Then enter your remote SQL server credential like below:

[image]

If the connection is alright you should get following:

[image]

It means that you have successfully able to connect. So try above steps I have provided.Hope that would guide you accordingly.

> ***Note:***
>
> `Trusted_Connection=false also allow you connect the database from your SQL server hosting provider` But as you are accessing with your
> server credential you can set that to `Trusted_Connection=true`.

Feel free to share if you have any further concern on it.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using userid and password for your new server, replace

```
Trusted_Connection=True;
```

with

```
Integrated Security=False;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you be able to connect SQL remotely? If it is working, then please double check your connection string or you can ask your provider about correct connection string that you need to use.