# Unable to login to SQL Server using connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I am trying to connect my .NET Core application to SQL Server using a connection string. However it is failing and I get this error:

> login failed for user

This is the connection string I am using

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultSQLConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-User\\MSSQLSERVER;Database=VillaDatabase;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
}
```

Below is the line of code I am using in my `Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option =>
{       
     option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultSQLConnection"));
});
```

I am currently using .NET Core 7.

Can anyone please tell me what could be the fix for this?

Comment: Please don't overwrite people's changes.

Comment: _"login failed for user"_ - the error is pretty self-explanatory and you haven't specified any form of username or trusted connection.   Depending on how you are hosting your ASP.NET Core website, the server will most likely be running it in the equivalent to `IIS_IUSRS` which most likely hasn't been granted access to your DB.  Either run the website in an explicit account or specify SQL Username+password in your config.

Comment: @Deleted I was trying using window authentication. DO i still need username for that?

Comment: No, but you have insufficient config even for WA

Answer (score 0):

We do in our application as:

1. Add connection string in **appsetting.json**

```
"connectionString": "data source=dbserver;initial catalog=dbname;user id=dbuserid;password=dbpassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=60;",
```

2. Read in c# code as

```
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        //.SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) + "/ThriivDental.DAL").AddJsonFile("config.json", false)
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/").AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{SessionModel.Environmentname}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .Build();
    string StaticConnectionString = configuration.GetSection("connectionString").Value;
```

Make sure the proper path of appsetting.json you get in above code. For your info, its added at project level (you can find near about startup.cs file)

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone please tell me what could be the fix for this.

In your `Server` Name which is `DESKTOP-User\\MSSQLSERVER` you should use your [server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047821/how-to-connecte-to-sql-sever-net6-visual-studio-2022-asp-net-mvc-project/71061188#71061188), not user. You can get the server information as below:

[image]

**Note:** First, try to login in `SSMS` using `user name` and `password` then use the same in your connection string.

Please refer to following [code snippet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047821/how-to-connecte-to-sql-sever-net6-visual-studio-2022-asp-net-mvc-project/71061188#71061188)

**Program.cs:**

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultSQLConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

**Appsetting.js When Login As User:**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultSQLConnection": "Server=YourServerName;Database=YourDatabaseName; User Id=User;password=Password; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
```

**Appsetting.js When Use Windows Authentication:**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultSQLConnection": "Server=YourServerName;Database=YourDatabaseName; Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
      },
```

**Note:** If you want to [`access database as an perticular user`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047821/how-to-connecte-to-sql-sever-net6-visual-studio-2022-asp-net-mvc-project/71061188#71061188) in that scenario include these two parameter `User Id=User;password=Password;`. In addition, if you would use `perticular user` in that case yon can remove `Trusted_Connection=True` but for `windown authentication` you could it to `true`.

If you need further details you could [`refer to our official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [`also this document`](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: I agree, As I am not sure, op's environment thus didn't explain, I will update the answer for sure. Thank you.

Comment: @Deleted Updated sir, now seems perfect.

Comment: thanks , the string as a User worked for me. However i had to add additional parameter of TrustedCertificate=True to the string. However Window Authentication is failing for the string though i am able to login to sql server  using window authentication

Comment: Thanks for your response,  glad to assist you on this, I hope it resolved your issue.